# Matplotlib: creating a figure and referring to existing axes/subplots

Tags: matplotlib, axis, subplot

I have the following (exemplary) code to produce three subplots.

```
fig1 = plt.figure()

s= -1.5

ax0 = plt.axes((0,0,1,1))
ax1 = plt.axes((0,s,1,1))
ax2 = plt.axes((0,s*2,1,1))

x = np.linspace(0,10)
ax0.plot(x,x*1)
ax1.plot(x,x*2)
ax2.plot(x,x**3)
```

I want to create a new figure which shows the three subplots **without** specifying the data and ax.plot lines. I want the code to execute the following: "create a figure with three subplots. Take the previously defined ax0 as the first subplot, ax1 as the second and ax2 as the third subplot".

I could not find a related thread - please refer me to the corresponding thread if this has been covered before.

Comment: Matplotlib doesn't support this functionality.  A subplot belongs to one and only one figure and can't be moved nor easily copied.  The recommended approach is to make a function that creates the subplots from data, and call that function multiple times.